# How to make a delay and "to bind" two variables?

Tags: solidity

I have a contract "luggage". The owner (e.g. me) needs to transfer it to the luggage room for a certain time. He can not get it earlier than the specified time.
Tell me, please:

a) how to make a "delay" (luggage cannot be collected before the delay has expired)

b) bind the owner's address with the luggage address (you can check that the luggage is requested by its owner)

```
contract LuggageStorage
{
    Luggage luggage;
    address owner;
    constructor(LuggageStorage _luggage) public 
    {
        luggage = _luggage;
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
    function storeLuggage (uint lAddress, uint time) public
    { 
        luggage.transferFrom(msg.sender, owner, lAddress); //the function transfers luggage to new owner
        
    }
    function retrieveLuggage(uint lAddress) public 
    {         
        luggage.transferFrom(owner, msg.sender, lAddress); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a delay, you can compare the [block.timestamp](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.3/units-and-global-variables.html#block-and-transaction-properties) global variable, which returns the current timestamp, to a previously stored timestamp.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract LuggageStorage {
    uint256 releaseDate;
    
    constructor(uint256 _releaseDate) {
        releaseDate = _releaseDate;
    }
    
    function retrieveLuggage() public {
        /*
         * `block.timestamp` is timestamp of the current transaction
         * `releaseDate` is the manually defined timestamp
         */

        require(block.timestamp >= releaseDate, "You're too early");

        // ... and here goes your retrieve implementation
    }
}
```

Checking for the owner is pretty much the same. You need to define the `owner` address and the validate against msg.sender.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract LuggageStorage {
    address owner;
    
    constructor(address _owner) {
        owner = _owner;
    }
    
    function retrieveLuggage() public {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Can by only requested by the owner");
        // ... here goes your retrieve implementation
    }
}
```

Feel free to look into some contracts by OpenZeppelin for more inspiration, especially [Ownable](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/access/Ownable.sol) and [Timelock](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/governance/TimelockController.sol).

Comment: Wow/ thanks. But I need to keep an unlimited amount of luggage from different owners. How can I implement this? It is more correct to rename the variable luggage to luggageRegister

Comment: In that case, you can create a mapping from luggage ID (since your `Luggage` is a struct, you can add an `uint` ID field if you don't have it already) to the `owner` address: `mapping (uint256 => address) luggageIdToOwner;` Or store the `releaseDate` and `owner` alltogether in the `struct Luggage`.